# AVAssetExportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: method Not Called

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, avassetexportsession

I'm combining two audio recordings (recorded using `AVAudioRecorder`) into one file. Using `AVAssetExportSession` to export the combined file works perfectly the first time (i.e. as long as I'm in the current view controller) 
But when load this view again (a new session) the `AVAssetExportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler`: method does not get called at all (no call back!)
No errors no nothing...
I tried to log the AVAssetExportSession object, i get this the first time

> ```
> <AVAssetExportSession: 0x155b3250, asset = <AVMutableComposition: 0x156474c0 tracks = ("<AVMutableCompositionTrack: 0x156a0bb0 trackID = 1, mediaType = soun, editCount = 0>")>, presetName = AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A, outputFileType = (null)
> ```

and this the second time

```
<AVAssetExportSession: 0x1559e840, asset = <AVMutableComposition: 0x155f7f30 tracks = ("<AVMutableCompositionTrack: 0x155f0120 trackID = 1, mediaType = soun, editCount = 1>")>, presetName = AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A, outputFileType = (null)
```

The only difference I noticed is the editCount = 1 thing.

I know it sounds confusing, it is to me. whatever is going on here?

My code:

```
AVAssetExportSession* exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession
                                       exportSessionWithAsset:composition
                                       presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

NSLog(@"exportSession: %@", exportSession);


exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:combined];
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    switch (exportSession.status) {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self exportDidFinish:exportSession];
    });

}];
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out what editCount was?

Answer (score 3):

It may or may not be related, but I have had a similar issue with videos.  The completion block won't fire if the export session doesn't have correct information about the `AVAsset` start time and duration.  The only workaround I found was to seek in a small amount of time for each asset when adding them to the composition track (`CMTimeRangeMake()`).  It's not ideal.

Comment: I need short time duration of my video.. duration below 1 second. How do to i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

it's Work correctly.

```
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         switch (exportSession.status) 
         {
                 case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                       NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
                 break;
                 case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                      NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
                      [self exportDidFinish:exportSession];
                 break;
                 case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
                     NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting");
                 break;
                 default:
                 break;
        }
    });
}];
```